# Web app server: How to Hide the Edit button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-app-server

I would like to hide the edit button when an Office Document is shown. Is this possible and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add following style in the master page

```
#flyoutWordViewerEdit-Medium {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give user a '*Read Only*' permission on document library.

- Go to **Library Settings > Permissions for this document library**
- **Stop Inheriting Permission**s
- **Grant 'Read' Permissions to user** you want.